# How to create index for spatial module for OrientDB (2.2.x)?

Tags: java, lucene, geospatial, orientdb, spatial

OrientDB has been upgrade to Spatial Module feature from 2.2.

What is the Java equivalent to create the index for this:

> CREATE INDEX  ON  (geometry-field) SPATIAL ENGINE
>   LUCENE

say, for the example:

```
ODocument location = new ODocument("OPoint");
location.field("coordinates", Arrays.asList(12.4684635, 41.8914114));

ODocument doc = new ODocument("Restaurant");
doc.field("name","Dar Poeta");
doc.field("location",location);

doc.save();
```

Ref: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Spatial-Index.html

(I saw some code here: [http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Spatial-Index.html] but seems this is for the previous version "spatial index", not "spatial module" from 2.2 onwards.)

Comment: See the updated documentation: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Spatial-Index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the index using OSQL via Java:

```
    db.command(new OCommandSQL("CREATE INDEX Restaurant.location ON Restaurant(location) SPATIAL ENGINE LUCENE")).execute();
```